# Haxe / OpenFL compile fails with "Unknown identifier : cpp"

Tags: haxe, openfl, hxcpp

Working on an OpenFL project, I updated a bunch of relevant Haxe libraries (hxcpp, openfl, lime, etc) and started getting a weird Haxe compiler error.

```
> lime test linux
CFFIPointer.hx:55: characters 23-81 : Unknown identifier : cpp
... (tons more of the same error)
```

I believe the line it was referencing was an `#if` compile switch on `cpp`. This should never fail as far as I know?

Notes:

- If you see this error, feel free to comment so we can identify the cause!
- Someone commented that `lime` and `openfl` commands are different, and technically they are, but OpenFL is built on Lime and the commands (`lime test linux` and `openfl test linux`) work interchangeably for my project.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the exact issue, but I fixed it by installing and switching to the official Haxe 3.2.0 from [haxe.org](http://haxe.org/) (I got the error while using Haxe 3.2.0-rc2 -- a release candidate build.)

Comment: I just had this problem on a mac. I had to downgrade to Haxe 3.2.0 and didn't see the 3.2.0 download link and grabbed the RC instead. Had I not seen this question I would have spent hours going down the wrong rabbit hole. One quick redownload and I'm back in business.